# Python: Replace integers by floats in string

Tags: python, string, replace, floating-point, integer

I'm looking for a way, to replace every number inside a string by a float number. So I'd turn this: `"3/1"` to this: `"3.0/1.0"`
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Will all strings have the numbers separated by a slash?

Comment: any type of number (integer, real, complex..) or integers only?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `re.sub` :

```
>>> s="3/1" 
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'\1.0',s)
'3.0/1.0'
>>> s="334/14" 
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'\1.0',s)
'334.0/14.0'
```

Comment: But - wait. If I insert a string like "1/30" it does weird things. ("3.00.0") is there another way? - EDIT: Solved. (\d+)

Comment: @d0n.key, you must be doing weird things then because you should not get that.

Comment: Just solved it, by changing (\d) in the function to (\d+)

Comment: @d0n.key if this answered your question, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the check mark to turn it green.

Comment: If the string contains a decimal number, this will screw things up.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Indeed, but its about numbers that format!

Answer (score 2):

If they are single strings always in the same format:

```
s = "3/1"


print("{}.0/{}.0".format(*s.split("/")))
```